# JDB(The Java Debugger) Command not accepting spaces in classpath option

Tags: java, jdb

I am debugging my code from [JDB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html)(Java Debugger). My Code uses the external jar files which I have kept in a separate folder.

If the path of external java files contains spaces then JDB gives the error.

[image: JDB Error when Path of external libraries is: C:\Users\raunak.choraria\Desktop\External Jars]

If path does not contains any spaces the program executes successfully.
[image: JDB success output when path of external libraries is: C:\Users\raunak.choraria\Desktop\ExternalJars]

My Path when the error occurs : C:\Users\raunak.choraria\Desktop\External Jars

My Path in case of successful execution : C:\Users\raunak.choraria\Desktop\ExternalJars

As per my understanding, from the point space character occurs it assumes it as class name and searches for the main class.

Comment: Where do you set that path? Depending on the context you could enclose the whole path in double-quotes, escape the space with a backslash, two backslash, or even use the dos form of the path

Comment: tried with the slash and double slash it did not work.
I think that jdb is removing the double quotes and because of this, the issue is occurring.